# How to not run audio if the timer is 00

Tags: javascript, debugging, audio, logic, pause

**Edited**: i want to create a feature that is when the countdown reaches 00:00:00 in the time, play's a little song to the user at the end of it.
Currently, the logic of the app is like this:

```js
// here when the timer reaches 00 at the countdown plays the song fine.
//but if the app is already at 00, and the user hits the button to initialize the countdown with the time at 00, the song plays anyway.
//i just want the song to play when the timer reaches 00 naturally, not at the beginning, without a value
function timer() {
  if (h.value == 0 && m.value == 0 && s.value == 0) {
    h.value = 0;
    m.value = 0;
    s.value = 0;
    stopCount()
    audio.play()
  } else if (s.value != 0) {
    s.value--;
    change.src = "./img/pause-btn.png"
  } else if (m.value != 0 && s.value == 0) {
    s.value = 59;
    m.value--;
    change.src = "./img/pause-btn.png"
  } else if (h.value != 0 && m.value == 0) {
    m.value = 60;
    h.value--;
    change.src = "./img/pause-btn.png"
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Off topic: `setInterval(initialize(), 1000)` you either wanted `setTimeout(initialize, 1000)` `setTimeout(() => initialize(), 1000)`or just `initialize()` - as it is, your code is the same as `var result = initialize(); setTimeout(result, 1000)`  as initialise() doesn't do anything, it runs immediately and there's no repeated call (interval).

Comment: Please add relevant HTML and CSS to the snippet I made you in a [mcve]

Comment: Seems to me your "reset" resets it down to zero rather than *resetting* back to the initial/start time.  In timer() when all are zero, it should also *reset* to start values rather than "reset to 0" (when it's already confirmed the values are zero)  Your code:  `if (x===0) { x = 0; }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timer function with user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73875215/timer-function-with-user-input)

Comment: No, sorry. I new here. But the point is: i just want to play the song when the timer reaches 00:00:00 naturally. If the app starts at 00:00:00 and doesn't have a value, and the user hit the button to run the countdown without any number, the song plays anyways

Comment: make a variable and check it to see if the counter has been started or not. if not then don't play the audio

Comment: FYI: Editing the question to remove the relevant code doesn't help your cause.  Given the current question, you might get close-voted as needing more info:  how is timer() called? What are h/m/s?

Comment: Easiest option is to check when you *start*, (not in the timer() function) - if it's 0/0/0 when you start, then don't start.